# Simulate A Gamepad Input With C#

Tags: c#, controller, joystick, emulation

I'll simplify the situation to get rid of confusion.

I want to make a program that only has 1 button in the program. Upon clicking the button, the program will simulate a generic gamepad button. I'm sure when the program starts, it will have to somehow emulate a gamepad. The gamepad that is being emulated should be visible in the Control Panel. (`joy.cpl` to be more specific)

I have to do this without making a driver or relying on a 3rd party library/API- I know it can be done this way since I've seen some programs that actually do this already but my program will have a completely different use than those. I cannot find any good information on where to start, so pushing me in the right direction would be nice or showing me some code in `C#` would be cool, too!

**Thanks, guys!**

Comment: How about [this](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/)?